# Does the browser request the javascript file if its not used?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am placing a reference to a javascript file in my masterpage. If I do not use javascript does the broswer still download it?

Comment: Do you mean, if you have JavaScript execution disabled in the browser does it still download?

Comment: I would have thought so - but it might depend on the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does.  If you have the script file linked in the page it will always attempt (caching and other factors can make it not necessary though) to download it.

If it didn't automatically download, how would the browser know when to get it?  Imagine how slow your first script call would be if it did it then.

Answer (score 2):

If you link to it in the HTML, the browser will download it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Si. Oui. Da. Ja.

Indubitably. Certainly. Affirmative. Positively. Definitively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The browser cannot read your mind and ascertain whether or not you intend to use the javascript.

Everything that is referenced in your masterpage will be downloaded by your browser.

If you want to see which files your browser downloads, go to a webpage and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and save the website in whatever folder you like. All the files that webpage references will also be saved in a separate folder (at least in IE and Chrome)